# Coefficient for a zero lag cross-correlation different from Pearson correlation r

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r, cross-correlation

Reading around I understood that using a cross correlation with lag zero should give the same results of a normal pearson correlation. It happens that this is not the case for me. What could be the reason? Could NAs values influence this?

R Code:

```
> Data.Wide.Weeks$Philadelphia.1.PA
 [1]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  63.00 199.00  81.70 335.00 284.00 455.00 797.00 671.00 368.00 164.00  76.00 150.00  43.00  33.70  18.30  10.00   7.67
[25]   8.33   6.00   5.33   6.67  30.30  21.00  23.30  49.00  80.30  28.00  31.00  18.00

> Data.Wide.Weeks$ArcWd
 [1]  65.3  74.1  77.7  97.4 117.0 138.0 186.0 200.0 204.0 241.0 392.0 337.0 350.0 505.0 380.0 351.0 230.0 242.0 199.0 166.0 100.0  98.1 129.0 113.0 101.0  95.7 101.0 104.0
[29] 121.0 148.0 167.0 182.0 159.0 139.0 137.0 144.0

> cor(Data.Wide.Weeks$ArcWd, Data.Wide.Weeks$Philadelphia.1.PA, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
[1] 0.9265837

> ccf(Data.Wide.Weeks$ArcWd, Data.Wide.Weeks$Philadelphia.1.PA, na.action = na.pass, plot =F, lag.max = 5)

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

   -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5 
0.175 0.349 0.540 0.668 0.835 0.949 0.793 0.635 0.466 0.301 0.176
```

The pearson coeff is 0.926, while the ccf zero lag coeff is 0.949, and this happens for all my series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple simulation **without** the NA values will show that `ccf` and `cor` give the same results. So the issue is with how `ccf` and `cor` treat NA values.

In your code you use `na.pass` for `ccf` and `pairwise.complete.obs` for `cor`. The documentation for `ccf` gives the following warning when using  `na.pass`:

> This means that the estimate computed may well not be a valid
>   autocorrelation sequence, and may contain missing values.

Now the option `pairwise.complete.obs` for `cor` omits the observations where either of series are NA. So if you want the same behaviour as `cor` you should do the same. Simple simulation shows that if you use `na.omit` instead of `na.pass` the `ccf` and `cor` give the same result.

Now the question is how exactly `ccf` calculates the covariances when `na.action=na.pass`? This can be seen by inspecting the code of `acf`, which `ccf` calls. Here is the offending line:

```
if (demean) 
        x <- sweep(x, 2, colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE), check.margin = FALSE)
```

The default option for `demean` is `TRUE`, if it is `FALSE` it is assumed that the means are zero. It is clear then that for `na.pass` the mean for the series without the NA values will be calculated from all of the observations, rather than from observations where both of the series are not NA.

So in the end the issue was the same as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399788/why-do-i-get-different-results-using-ccf-and-cor-in-r) mentione by @lekshmi dharmarajan. The scaling is different when NA values are treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not considered an answer, this would be more a comment. However I am posting this here since I do not have enough reputation yet, given I am relatively new... Have you looked at this post, maybe this gives can give you a direction.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399788/why-do-i-get-different-results-using-ccf-and-cor-in-r

Comment: Thanks, but your example refer to the difference that arise when the lag is applied because ccf use the baseline mean and sd on the assumption of stationarity. In my case I see the difference even at lag zero, where this assumption should be respected by default.